# How do Advaitins respond to the Vishishtadvaitic argument that attaining the state of Kaivalya does not lead to liberation?

Tags: advaita, karma, moksha, vishishtadvaita, kaivalya

[In this Vishishtadvaitc work called Siddhanta sangraha](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/siddhanta-sangraha-sailacharya/d/doc427519.html), the author Sri Shailacharya, a Vishishtadvaitin of the Rāmānuja school argues-

> One who is interested in kaivalya-bhoga is included in amumukṣu
> category. It is because in the case of the kaivalyaniṣṭa there is no
> cessation of his karma in its entirety

He further claims

> The kevala will definitely get back to saṃsāra; when his karma is left
> with him. Moreover the kaivalyaniṣṭa will not reach the path of
> light[2] (arcirādigati) as there are the remains of karma. But for the
> spiritual practitioner (parabrahma upāsaka) the archirādigati (the
> path of light) is the only path as stated in the sutras.

Further more the author argues that only bhakti yogis come under the category of the aspirants of liberation-

> **Whereas for the kevala, the rebirth is unavoidable as he has only the dhūmādi mārga (the path of smoke).** The category namely mumukṣu
> also divided into two.Those who are devoted to the path of surrender
> (nyāsaniṣṭa) and those who are adept in the practice of bhaktiyoga.

According to the arguments given by the Above, Kaivalya moksha does not involve complete cessation of Karmas, therefore entailing rebirth even after one may have attained it.

How do the Advaitins respond to this argument?

Comment: What is kaivalya for VA is not same as advaitic moksha. For VA, kailvalya is end product of jeeva upAsana. Advaitic moksha is end product of jnAna of aikya between jeeva and brahman.

Comment: @estimator What's this concept of Jeeva Upasana in Vishishtadvaita ? How is it different from Advaitic kaivalya?

Comment: check this -  https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?scram=1&etradi=1&choose=1&&language=dv&field_chapter_value=12&field_nsutra_value=1

Comment: and this - https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?scram=1&etradi=1&choose=1&&language=dv&field_chapter_value=12&field_nsutra_value=3

Comment: For advaitin, these Gita slokas refer to saguNa and nirguNa brahman "upAsakas" (for lack of a better word). For VA, these slokas refer to brahman and jIva upAsakas.